# Rails - How to build an Array of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following 2 models:

```
Projects, has_many projects
Users belong_to Projects

@project = Project.find(1)
@project.users --- outputs a lot of users
```

What I want to be able to do is the following: Given a list of say 3 projects (1,4,11), iterate over each project's users and build an object with all the users across the three projects, first combining, while not duplicating.

Here is what I have so far, but it's not working correctly:

```
  @aggregate_users = Array.new


  params[:project_list].split(/, ?/).each do |project|
      @project_temp = Project.find(project)
      @project_temp.users.each do |user|
        @aggregate_users << user
      end
  end
```

Suggestions? Also, how to avoid duplicate users from being added?
 Thanks

Comment: If ":user belongs_to :project", how is it possible that you get duplicate users?

Comment: Agree with @tokland here - if users belong_to projects, then "John" who belongs to Project A is technically a _dffierent_ user than "John" from Project B (even though they have the same name, they'll be separate objects in your DB - even `.uniq!` won't help you here).  Perhaps it would make more sense to use [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure Ruby approach:

```
@users = Project.find(project_ids).map(&:users).flatten.uniq
```

SQL approach (as you say a *user* belongs to a *project*):

```
@users = User.where(:project_id => project_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by sticking to rails convention

```
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :users
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :project
  end
```

Next,lets say you have @projects, which holds those three projects you mentioned (or more)

```
  @needed_users = Array.new

  @projects.each do |project|
     project.users.each do |user|
        if !@needed_users.includes?(user)
           @needed_users.push(user)
        end
     end
  end
```